# How can I batch install fonts (Kubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, fonts

Hello and thank you for your help.
I need to install many fonts. Currently, the only way I know is to click on each one, and hit "install" when "Font Viewer" opened them, hit "system" button, and enter my password. It is a long, and time-wasting process. I need to know:
1. Is there any command that I can batch install my fonts? 
2. If not, is there any graphical program that does the job?
3. Is there any way that I can just copy my fonts to some directory? (I don't know where the fonts are installed)
Thanks again

Comment: If you don't need them to be available for other users, just create a local directory `~/.fonts` and drag all fonts at once into the directory.

Comment: Thanks Jacob Vlijm for your answer. There's no other user; It's just me and root (myself!) And I need them in both modes.

Answer (score 5):

**KDE Font Management**

KDE System Settings > Font Management

The KDE System Settings has a search:

[image]

Font Management - click the 'Add' button and pick the wanted fonts (.tff)

[image]

The KDE Font Manager has the handbook - The 'Help' button

[image]

or from the net: https://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kde-workspace/kcontrol/fontinst/index.html

Comment: Wow! I can't imagine any easier way. Thank you. Still one question: Is there any command to run in terminal that does batch font installation? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to batch install fonts **for use by your user** is to copy the font files to the `~/.fonts` directory in your user's home directory.

```
$ cp *.ttf ~/.fonts/
```

If the fonts are to be **available to other users on the system** including the root user, then as root copy the font files to the `/usr/share/fonts/` directory.

```
$ sudo cp *.ttf /usr/share/fonts/
```